# Find the column number of the first of 3 consecutive positive cells on a row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have these values on a row:

```
-9  -7   5  -1  10  3  -13  2  15  60 -4
```

I want to find the column number of the first of 3 consecutive positive numbers on a row. In this example, the first 3 consecutive positive numbers are 2  15  60, so I want the column of the cell with number "2", which is H (column number 8).

What formula can I use the achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
=MATCH(1,INDEX((A1:I1>0)*(B1:J1>0)*(C1:K1>0),),0)
```

Comment: Is that a CSE formula?  Can you explain the INDEX portion a bit since after the comma is blank which is where I would normally expect a position value of somesort

Comment: @ForwardEd It would normally be a CSE formula, but INDEX forces it to calculate as a CSE formula without requiring CSE entry (makes it easier for the OP to enter since no CSE required this way).  You could instead leave off the INDEX and CSE the formula to get the same result.  The reason the INDEX argument is left blank is so that it returns the full array of values to MATCH against, instead of returning a single value which would make the outer MATCH useless.